# How to find out why my iPhone just beeped?

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications

Sometimes when I have the ring/silent switch set to "ring", my iPhone will beep, and I don't know why.

I've got some apps set to notify with sound, so this is totally fine with me.  There's other AskDifferent questions which are basically "How to stop the beeping?", and that's not this.  I don't want to stop it.

I want to learn what the beep means.  When I've got 3 apps which are allowed to beep, how am I supposed to figure out what a beep means?  There's no visible notifications when I swipe down.  No app icon has a red badge on it.

Is it expected that I should only have beeps enabled for one app?  Otherwise, what exactly am I supposed to do with the knowledge that something happened, but I'm not told what?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  For the apps that you've set to notify you with sound, do you also have them set to visually notify you?  If you don't let them send a notification or display a red circle with a number, you won't know which one went off.

Comment: How do you know which app sends the sound. I don't know which ones I have set to notify with sound.